# Having trouble passing a slug to UpdateView so that it gets the correct data

Tags: python, django, django-views, slug, django-generic-views

I am trying to allow a user to edit the information entered into their project using UpdateView. I kept getting an error saying "Generic detail view UpdateProject must be called with either an object pk or a slug." I have tried pointing to the slug within the UpdateView class, but can't get it to work. I am new to Django, so any help would be much appreciated!

views

```
class CreateProject(CreateView):
    model = UserProject
    form_class = UserProjectForm
    template_name = 'howdidu/create_project.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        userproject = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        userproject.save()
        self.object = userproject
        return super(CreateProject, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        project_username = self.request.user.username
        project_slug = self.object.slug
        return reverse('user_project', kwargs={'username':project_username, 'slug': project_slug})

class UpdateProject(UpdateView):
    model = UserProject
    form_class = UserProjectForm
    template_name = 'howdidu/update_project.html'
    slug_field = 'slug'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        userproject = form.save(commit=False)
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        userproject.save()
        self.object = userproject
        return super(UpdateProject, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        project_username = self.request.user.username
        project_slug = self.object.slug
        return reverse('user_project', kwargs={'username':project_username, 'slug': project_slug})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
        url(r'^register_profile/$', views.register_profile, name='register_profile'),
        url(r'^update_profile/$', views.update_profile, name='update_profile'),
        url(r'^create_project/$', login_required(views.CreateProject.as_view()), name='create_project'),
        url(r'^update_project/$', login_required(views.UpdateProject.as_view()), name='update_project'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile_page, name='user_profile'),
        url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.project_page, name='user_project'),
        )
```

models

```
class UserProject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_overview = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    project_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='project_images', blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    project_views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    project_followers = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True) #should this be unique or not?

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(UserProject, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: the url is update_project/ that I am trying to get to when the error comes up

Answer (score 1):

Django's UpdateView requires pk or slug parameter coming from the corresponding url by default. In your case you need to change the url to your UpdateProject view to

```
url(r'^update_project/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    login_required(views.UpdateProject.as_view()),
    name='update_project'),
```

where slug is your project's slug.

Comment: hmmm I tried that but it didn't seem to work. Could I be doing something wrong or need to change something else? I kept the slug_field = 'slug' in UpdateView.

Comment: This url means that you need to pass project's slug in the url for UpdateProject. For example, if you have project with slug 'projectslug' than this url should work

update_project/projectslug/

Comment: how can I pass the projects slug? sorry I am really struggling with this :-(

Answer (score 0):

create a utils.py file in your app. using slugify from django utils.

```
import random
import string


from django.utils.text import slugify



def random_string_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
    return "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


def unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=None):
    if new_slug is None:
        slug = new_slug
    else:
        slug=slugify(instance.model field of your choice)
    Klass = instance.__class__
    qs_exists = Klass.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists()
    if qs_exists:
        new_slug = "{slug}-{randstr}".format(
            slug=slug,
            randstr=random_string_generator(size=4)
            )
        return unique_slug_generator(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug
```

add a slug to your model

```
slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
```

add it to your urls.py file

```
url(r'^update/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', profileUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserProject(UpdateView):
    model = BlogSlider
    fields = ['title', 'sub_title', 'description', 'image']
    template_name = 'update.html'
```

use a form and use {{ form.as_p }}.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.